# Add a simple request css

Tags: php, css

Sorry for my bad English

i have this code php

i want add css to the code

```
<?php
$post_objects = get_field('awncn');

if( $post_objects ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
   <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
            <h1><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ); ?></h1>

        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif;
?>
```

I want such a beautiful shape
http://prntscr.com/aqf4ht

Comment: Do you already have the CSS in an external stylesheet?

Comment: css style rules are best added no inline but as separate files referenced in the documents head. So something like `<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>` which refers to a file (or resource) `theme.css` that is fetched by a separate request the browser does.

Comment: You will have to start by adding `class` properties to your `HTML` code. Add some `<div></div>` tags as well.

Comment: I would start with reading something about `html` and `css` ... would help you alot.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I want someone that modifies the code to suit the image

Comment: @arkascha Yes, I know, but my very weak css and I can not work like him

Comment: The way _how_ you refer to your css rule does not in any way change the rules themselves. I only pointed out _how_ to reference them. I don't see any reason why you apparently think you are unable to do so...

Comment: @RST Yes, but I can not write because I weak CSS code and I want a person who wrote this code

Comment: @arkascha This is the form in which I have http://prntscr.com/aqgwkj i need help in writing css code

Comment: Please prepare a fiddler (jsfiddle.net) with your final html markup that we can play around with.

Comment: @arkascha https://jsfiddle.net/mepfanms/

Comment: Keep in mind stackoverflow is about "code you created that is not working" not that much about "I need some code can anyone supply it". Glad someone could help you out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rearrange your markup a bit to make it stylable, but apart from that things look pretty straight forward:

The (slightly modified) html markup:

```
<div class="awncn">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img width="150" height="150" 
                     src="http://i1.wp.com/drama-online.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Screenshot_9.png?resize=150%2C150" 
                     class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" 
                     alt="Screenshot_9">
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="http://drama-online.tv/dramanews/23232323/">23232323</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img width="150" height="150" 
                     src="http://i2.wp.com/drama-online.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/21006-207x272.jpg?resize=150%2C150" 
                     class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" 
                     alt="21006-207x272">
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="http://drama-online.tv/dramanews/thrthtrhrthrthtrh/">thrthtrhrthrthtrh</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The css style rules:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
figure {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
figure figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
figure figcaption a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is the modified variant of the fiddler you posted:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ssq0fu9p/2/
```

Comment: Thank you!
I am very happy to help me

Comment: :-) You are welcome! Good luck with your project!